# How to handle auto-uploaded file in cancelled form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my scenario:

1. I have a form with some information like full name, birthday... and one input is filesupload with an auto upload option
2. If I use auto aupload, files will be uploaded to server before the form is submitted. If user cancels form submission, The db record is not created hence I do not need the file uploaded anymore and this lead to trash files on my server.

Is there any way I can handle this so i do not have too many trash files in the upload folder on the server?

Comment: Jinx, you should consider changing the question title or re-writing it to be better understood. However, i think i understand your dilemma. Check out my answer below.

Comment: @Jinx how did you solve this at the end?? I am facing the same situation as you were

Answer (score 0):

Form your question i think what you want to do is to be able to delete a file if the the form data is not submitted and the file has auto-uploaded right?...

These are two ways to achieve this:

**1. Do not auto-upload in the first place**

There is no real reason why you should upload the file itself to server FILE_UPLOAD_FOLDER. Instead, convert the file into a base64 string which you can save in your db instead of using the file-path as link. When you want to render you can convert the string back to a file

**2. Create a method that listens to the cancel button click.**

I would assume that you have a variable that holds FILE_UPLOAD_PATH, hence just create a javascript function to delete the file and put it in the onClick attribute of the cancel button.

Comment: 1.So why dropzone js, alpaca js file upload always autoupload. How can i upload with form submission?  2.User just dont click to cancel button, or do nothing, or just close browser, or computer shutdown... This method not good.

Comment: I need user can review, i can validate file input before submit form. After user can edit (show image uploaded, remove file uploaded with javascipt action, submit to confirm this action)